# How to configure @Controller and @RequestMapping

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a controller class using annotations for request mapping however it does not seem to be recognized when I try to connect browser to it

When I try to connect using url http://localhost:8088/carMart
I get the error:
The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Controller class:

```
package com.store.controller

@Controller
public class CarMartController {
    @RequestMapping("/carMart")
    public String navigateToCarMart( ModelMap model) {
        return "carMart";
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
    <description>
        Configuration file for the Store Application
    </description>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/store-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>store</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>        
      <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>store</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

store-servlet.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package = "com.store" />
<context:annotation-config/>

<bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
  <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/jquery/**" location="/jquery/"/>

<import resource="/spring/store.xml" />
<import resource="/hibernate/hibernate-configuration.xml" />
```

I have tried various combinations for the RequestMapping but always the same issue, also tried setting base-package to com.store.controller but still same error

Comment: Ditch the `ContextLoaderListener` and remove the `contextConfigLocation` from the `DispatcherServlet`. Redeploy/restart your application. By default the `DispatcherServlet` (actually the `HandlerMapping` implementations) doesn't look at the parent context for controllers, hence nothing will be found.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your prompt response, I have made the changes, redeployed the app, cleared the cache in browser but still get the same problem

Comment: Also make sure that the JSP is in the correct location and that it is available. Also make sure that you are calling the URL, unless your application is named `ROOT.war` (when deploying to Tomcat) it won't be accessible on `/` but rather on the name of the war file . So your url should probably be something like ` http://localhost:8088/<name-of-war>/carMart ` (name of war is without the .war).

Comment: Hi, the war file is named store, changing url as you suggested worked great, thanks again, much appreciated